# Why did I get 250 Station Cash?

Tags: planetside-2

I logged into Planetside 2 for the first time, and the thing that was different compared to all my friends is that I had 250 station cash. I can not seem to find any reason why I received it. The only thing I can think of is that I played Everquest I & II , and the original Planetside. I was not in the beta. Was there some promotion I missed?

Comment: I also had 250 SC that I had received for playing an earlier SOE game. I believe they give you a one time small sum of SC in the hopes of encouraging you to buy more.

Comment: Did you participate in the Facebook Recruit Center?

Comment: @MapCavalier nope definitely did not

Comment: I doubt this can be answered. If anything, contact SOE and ask them why, they have your account info and such.

Comment: @MapCavalier At this point I agree with you. I was thinking it was some promotion that I couldn't find but if you want to post that as an answer I'll graciously accept it.

Comment: Really appreciate that, thank you :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a mistake or some transaction may have happened you were not aware of. I honestly cant tell, but if you contact SOE they can check your history and probably can at least find out why you received it.